# JavaEE/JSF/Mock/NullPointerExceptionエラーを解除したい

Tags: java-ee, jsf

JavaEEで部署管理アプリを作成しております。
新規部署登録処理のテストコードを作成しましたが、
NullPointerExceptionエラーが発生してしまい、解除できず困っています。
解決法を教えていただけたら助かります。（画像5枚）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ソースコードは画像としてではなく、テキストのまま質問文に含めてください。画像にしてしまうと回答のための引用等が難しくなります。

Comment: 肝心かなめのスタックトレース隠れていて何が起きているのかさっぱりです。

Comment: 明けてみてみて、理解しました。その部分は社名か何かはいっているんですね。さらしても構わない形にパッケージを変えて（リファクタリング機能を使えば一瞬）実行すれば、余計な手間を省けますよ。画像でとって白で埋めてって割と手間なわりにそもそも、つぶし忘れればさらされるわけで、根元を変えたほうが安全なのかなと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getResouceBundle内で利用されているcontextもしくはcontext.getApplicationの戻り値のいずれかがNullだからでは？
Unitテストでの実行とのことで、本来JSFがうめてくれるcontextが空なのかと思います。
テストの実行範囲を絞って（また、しぼれるようにメソッドを適切に分割して）実施するか、contextをモックオブジェクトで置き換える、置き換えているのなら、getApplicationがnullを返さないように差配する必要があります。
また、nullで返す可能性がある箇所でメソッドの多段呼び(α.getA.doB.doC)のような書き方は微妙かと、α、A,Bのどれがnullかスタックトレースからわからないので。
この実装をしていても、今回のようにnullがでてくる場合、デバッガで実行するか、行を分けて書いて一度実行。どれがnullかを切り分ければ、答えは早いかと。

Comment: わかりやすい解説、ありがとうございました。